# How to manually segment and label ROIs in an image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, image-segmentation

I'm a newbie to Matlab. I'm basically attempting to manually segment a set of images and then manually label those segments also. I looked into the imfreehand(), but I'm unable to do this using imfreehand().

Basically, I want to follow the following steps :

1. Manually segment various ROIs on the image (imfreehand only lets me draw one segment I think?)
2. Assign labels to all those segments
3. Save the segments and corresponding labels to be used further (not sure what format they would be stored in, I think imfreehand would give me the position and I could store that along with the labels?)
4. Hopefully use these labelled segments in the images to form a training dataset for a neural network.

If there is some other tool or software which would help me do this, then any pointers would be very much appreciated. (Also I am new to stackoverflow, so if there is any way I could improve on the question to make it clearer, please let me know!) Thanks!

Comment: You might find [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23466004/1714410) useful. It uses `imfreehand`, but allows for more than one region to be drawn.

Answer (score 2):

Derek Hoiem, a computer vision research at the University of Illinois, wrote an object labelling tool which does pretty much exactly what you asked for.  You can download it from his page:

http://www.cs.illinois.edu/homes/dhoiem/software/index.html